# Ubuntu 18.04 Wifi stops working after 30 min

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, atheros

My wifi seems to be working fine but in case of my laptop sometimes it stops working but at the same time in my phone I can see internet is working fine.

My network information:

```
shashank@shashank:~$ lspci -v | grep -i network -A 6
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device 08a6
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 132
    Memory at b4000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Also with little research I got to know that we can see messages when something happen using `dmesg`, correct me if I am wrong.

So after analyzing this output I noticed this:

```
[24509.560661] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[24510.252812] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: device successfully recovered
[24845.166738] wlp3s0: AP a0:04:60:b3:0f:c8 changed bandwidth, new config is 2452 MHz, width 1 (2452/0 MHz)
[25270.900105] wlp3s0: deauthenticating from a0:04:60:b3:0f:c8 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[25274.068463] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[25274.156226] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp3s0: link is not ready
[25283.293078] wlp3s0: authenticate with a0:04:60:b3:0f:c8
[25283.333453] wlp3s0: send auth to a0:04:60:b3:0f:c8 (try 1/3)
[25283.337766] wlp3s0: authenticated
[25283.339614] wlp3s0: associate with a0:04:60:b3:0f:c8 (try 1/3)
[25283.343734] wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from a0:04:60:b3:0f:c8 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=2)
[25283.347569] wlp3s0: associated
[25283.347726] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp3s0: link becomes ready
-> [26352.701156] wlp3s0: AP a0:04:60:b3:0f:c8 changed bandwidth, new config is 2452 MHz, width 2 (2442/0 MHz)
-> [26352.739538] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware crashed! (uuid a5f4c229-c922-4966-9e9f-8d649be77a51)
[26352.739588] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: qca9377 hw1.1 target 0x05020001 chip_id 0x003821ff sub 11ad:08a6
[26352.739601] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: kconfig debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[26352.741855] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 api 5 features ignore-otp crc32 79cea2c7
[26352.743404] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: board_file api 2 bmi_id N/A crc32 93da0176
[26352.743422] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: htt-ver 3.1 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1
[26352.745460] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: firmware register dump:
[26352.745491] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [00]: 0x05020001 0x000015B3 0x00985B3A 0x00955B31
[26352.745512] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [04]: 0x00985B3A 0x00060730 0x00000004 0x00000001
[26352.745531] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [08]: 0x00955A00 0x00438830 0x00450888 0x00420970
[26352.745556] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [12]: 0x00000009 0x00000000 0x00952CD0 0x00952CE6
[26352.745575] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [16]: 0x00952CC4 0x0091080D 0x00000000 0x0091080D
[26352.745594] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [20]: 0x40985B3A 0x0040E788 0x00400000 0x00421888
[26352.745614] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [24]: 0x809BF546 0x0040E7E8 0x00426470 0xC0985B3A
[26352.745635] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [28]: 0x809B90D8 0x0040E958 0x00000018 0x0042EA0C
[26352.745655] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [32]: 0x809B859A 0x0040E9A8 0x0040E9CC 0x00428D74
[26352.745675] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [36]: 0x8091D252 0x0040E9C8 0x00000000 0x00000001
[26352.745695] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [40]: 0x809EDD7B 0x0040EA78 0x00437544 0x00429428
[26352.745715] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [44]: 0x809EB6A6 0x0040EA98 0x00437544 0x00000001
[26352.745735] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [48]: 0x80911210 0x0040EAE8 0x00000010 0x004041D0
[26352.745755] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [52]: 0x80911154 0x0040EB28 0x00400000 0x00000000
[26352.745775] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [56]: 0x8091122D 0x0040EB48 0x00000000 0x00400600
[26352.745791] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: Copy Engine register dump:
[26352.745822] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [00]: 0x00034400   5   5   3   3
[26352.745854] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [01]: 0x00034800  26  26 167 168
[26352.745884] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [02]: 0x00034c00  47  47  46  47
[26352.745913] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [03]: 0x00035000   1   1   2   1
[26352.745943] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [04]: 0x00035400 4953 4953 238 174
[26352.745977] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [05]: 0x00035800   0   0   0   0
[26352.746010] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [06]: 0x00035c00  27  27  27  27
[26352.746043] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: [07]: 0x00036000   1   1   1   1
[26352.778157] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[26353.479867] ath10k_pci 0000:03:00.0: device successfully recovered
[27985.880150] wlp3s0: AP a0:04:60:b3:0f:c8 changed bandwidth, new config is 2452 MHz, width 1 (2452/0 MHz)
[28178.609369] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

I have indicated with `->` to show that I am pointing to. So as soon bandwidth config is changed, then the firmware is getting crashed. So can anyone help me that how I can fix this.

Full output:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove installed Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 firmware

```
sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/*
```

Download and install `board.bin`:

```
sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
```

Download and install `board-2.bin`:

```
sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA9377/hw1.0/board-2.bin
```

Download and install `firmware-5.bin`:

```
sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA9377/hw1.0/WLAN.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00002-QCATFSWPZ-5
```

Remove `ath10k` kernel module:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
```

Load `ath10k` kernel module:

```
sudo modprobe -v ath10k_pci
```

Observe if the installed new firmware works well.

**Do described below only if some problems with installed above firmware appear!**

If some problem appear, try another `firmware-5.bin` file. Remove installed file:

```
sudo rm /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```

Download and install another `firmware-5.bin`:

```
sudo wget -O /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/raw/master/QCA9377/hw1.0/CNSS.TF.1.0/firmware-5.bin_CNSS.TF.1.0-00267-QCATFSWPZ-1
```

Remove `ath10k` kernel module:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci
```

Load `ath10k` kernel module again:

```
sudo modprobe -v ath10k_pci
```

Check if everything works properly.

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply. I tried the first part of your answer and there was no error while installing it. And so far there is no firmware crash detected so I guess it is working fine. Thank you so much for your answer :)